# Index Prefix Length for BLOB with Nhibernate and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In my data model there is a class with a `byte[] Hash` property, which is translated into BLOB. I want this column/property to be unique.

According to this MySQL manual [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html), I need to specify an index prefix length for the BLOB otherwise it doesn't allow indexing on BLOB.

```
CREATE TABLE test (blob_col BLOB, INDEX(blob_col(10)));
```

In (Fluent) NHibernate how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

database-object in a hbm.xml file or string and `new Configuration.Configure().Add()`

http://ayende.com/blog/3947/nhibernate-mapping-database-object

Comment: Thanks.
The programmatic way is to call `new Configuration.Configure().AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject)`. For convenience, there is a [SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Mapping/SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject.cs?revision=6038&view=markup)